# Form Authentication problem within frame on redirect after Window 10 14-Jan update

Tags: asp.net, windows-10, frame, forms-authentication, response.redirect

I am using form authentication in my asp.net application, my application can be used as punchout, where other application can use my application with prior authentication, however, it was suddenly stops working after receiving windows 10 update from Microsoft.

My catalog application used to open in frame, the flow is : after receiving  punchout request, the request is being validated, authenticated and then system will redirect it to catalog home page using response.redirect. however, we lost control while redirect to home page and landed on form authentication login url.

below is sample code which authenticate the punchout request and redirect to main page (i.e. default.aspx)

```
private void AuthenticatePunchoutUser()
{   
    String punchoutid = Request["punchout"].ToString(); 

    //Create a PunchoutDB object and Authenticate the punchout request
    ePlus.Catalog.DataTypes.cXMLPunchout oPunchout = null;
    try
    {
        ePlus.Catalog.DataTypes.cXMLPunchoutDB oPunchoutDB = new ePlus.Catalog.DataTypes.cXMLPunchoutDB();
        oPunchout = oPunchoutDB.AuthenticatePunchout(punchoutid);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e2)
    {           
        ePlus.Data.Global.Log.Error("Error authenticating punchout session with punchoutid= " + punchoutid, e2);
        throw;
    }   
    //Log that the user was authenticated
    ePlus.Data.Global.Log.Info("Authenticated punchout User " + strUserName);   

    //Tell Forms Authentication that the user is valid 
    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(oUser.Login, false);

    String strRedirect = "~/Secure/Default.aspx";

    //Redirect
    this.Page.Response.Redirect(strRedirect);                        
}
```

on response.redirect, the application redirected to the login page (i.e. form authentication login url).

Comment: debug your code, put a breakpoint on Secure/Default.aspx page_load()

Comment: i have already put debug point at there, before it gets executed it was again redirected to login page from where i have written response.redirect.